# Can't enable cookie in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, reactjs, webview

My javascript is running in a webview on android device. And I want to use cookie in the webview to save some user information. Below is my java code:

```
private WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new CourseBarCodeScanner(this), "courseBarCodeScanner");

        setupWebView();
    }
private void setupWebView() {
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(this.getFilesDir().getPath());
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });
        CookieManager cookieMgr = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieMgr.setAcceptCookie(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            cookieMgr.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
        }
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index_android.html");
    }
```

with the above code my javascript couldn't read or set anything on the cookies. I have used below code to enable cookie but it doesn't work.

```
cookieMgr.setAcceptCookie(true);
```

When I run my javascript on the browser everything works fine. How to enable cookies on android webview?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.

Instead of instantiate the webview with findViewById, I did

```
webview = new Webview(Activity.this);
```

You can also refer to the CookieManager :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

EDIT

I realize I added the webview dynamically.

With XML, you can use this to allow cookies in all app webviews :

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

Comment: In this way how can I add the webview on the UI?

Comment: Please see my code I already have called this method setAcceptCookie(true)